# How to return json data from 400 error to React from Express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have an array of errors on my backend which I want to send back to client to display.

I'm making the request in my action like so

```
export const registerUser = registeredUserData => async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await axios.post('/user/register', registeredUserData);
};
```

And on backend I have something like this

```
if (errors && errors.length) {
    res.status(400).json({ errors });
  }
```

My question is how can I get errors array back to the client?

I tried wrapping `await` in `try catch` but `error` in `catch` only contains a name of `error` and it doesn't have the `data`.

What works is if I get rid of `status(400)`. Then it is gets handled like succesfull call and data is assigned to `response` variable.

Is there a way to keep status of error and at the same time catch the data on client side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
        console.log(error.response.data); // => the response payload 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use try/catch in your function

```
try {
    const response = await axios.post('/user/register', registeredUserData);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

When success request comes then you will get data in the `response` or `catch` block will print the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://github.com/axios/axios),

```
export const registerUser = registeredUserData => async (dispatch) => {
  axios.post('/user/register', registeredUserData)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```